# npm install module in current directory

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run:

```
npm install my-app
```

The app is installed into node_modules/my-app/...

I also tried

```
npm install -g my-app
```

But that doesn't work either.

How can I install the module straight into the current directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location#answer-14867050 this answers your question

Comment: A feature request has been made: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1578

Answer (score 60):

`npm install` installs packages either [locally or globally](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/):

- **Locally**: `npm` looks for an existing folder called `node_modules` in the current directory and creates a folder for each package you install in that folder.  If it can't find an existing `node_modules` folder here, it then looks through the current directory's ancestors until it finds one.  If it can't find one, it creates one in the current directory.
- **Globally**: if you use the `-g` (global) option, the package is installed in a global location.  This location varies per Linux distribution, but  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/packagename` is one example.  CentOS7 uses `/usr/lib/node_modules/packagename`.

You should only use `-g` when the package is something you'd want to use as a command.

> Just like how global variables are kind of gross, but also necessary
>   in some cases, global packages are important, but best avoided if not
>   needed.
>
> In general, the rule of thumb is:
>
> 1. If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program,
>      using `require('whatever')`, then install it locally, at the root of
>      your project.
> 2. If you’re installing something that you want to use in
>      your *shell*, on the command line or something, install it globally, so
>      that its binaries end up in your `PATH` environment variable.

npm will not install a package's files directly into the current directory.

However, this is actually a good thing.  It keeps dependencies' files separate from your app, and [Node automatically searches the `node_modules` folder when you `require` something](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

Comment: Your first bullet is only slightly true. If there is no `./node_modules/` folder in the current directory, then npm will search the ancestor directories until it finds one with `node_modules/` in it. If it finds one, let's say in the grandparent directory, then  `npm install packagename` will install `packagename` in `../../node_modules/`. However if it searches up the file tree until it reaches the root and still does not find any `node_modules/` folders, then you are correct, npm will automatically generate that folder in the current directory and install the package there.

Comment: Thanks. It was doing the ancestor directory thing for me, I just created a folder locally and voila.

Comment: Thanks! That parent folder traversing was my issue.

Comment: I am creating Node app and wanted to keep Server related packages separate from Client related packages. So when I go to folder where I need my client packages, npm insall <pkg> --save would go to  parent node_module and add <pkg> in that location. You can instead just do npm init ; which will create package.json in current folder and then running npm install will create in in current folder. Thanks @achedeuzot

Comment: @chharvey I made an edit -- does that clarify it well enough?

Comment: just checked - it is not working, at least in 6.4.1

Comment: A feature request has been made for that purpose: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1578

Comment: `npm will automatically generate that folder in the current directory and install the package there.`
v3.10 that seems not to be the case. Should I just create the directory?

Answer (score 39):

As @dalu said, if you want to have local packages, you'll need a `package.json` file.

But to create the `package.json` file, you will have to **initialize npm** by running `npm init`.

You can then use `npm install <module_name> --save[-dev]`.

Comment: I'm glad I read the 'second' best answer. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 28):

This is how you can install a module to your current directory:

`npm i --prefix ./ my-app`

As others have said, the proper way is to configure your project via `package.json`

Comment: the most simple solution!

Comment: this is what i would want, but will not work - test case: `npm i --prefix ./ adolfintel/speedtest#node && ls`

Comment: this installs node_modules directory in your current directory. it then installs the node module in that directory.

Answer (score 5):

I think the real question, what I and the OP would want, is to install `my-app` like you would install an application. *i.e. Install a top level application, that I am going to "use" as an application and not "require" as a module.*

The fact that **npm** installs one level down from my application
directory, is a purely aesthetic objection by new npm users.

When I started using npm (not so long ago), I solved it by having a *git project* as an installer, clone the git, run the install script, but now I am used to it and it does not bother me to have the app in the "wrong" folder any more.

Just setup some `.sh`, `.bat` or short cuts in the right place
and your users won't notice.

Answer (score 4):

You ought to have a `package.json` in your current directory.

Then write `npm install <module_name> --save-dev` or `npm install <module_name> --save` and it will install to the node_modules directory

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows 7.
I had installed nodejs in a different folder (**c:\develop\nodejs**) to the one that was suggested while installing (**C:\Program Files\nodejs**)
I am totally new to nodejs or npm. i may not be talking the nodejs or npm language.
After installing nodejs. I had to do some commands like this in the main nodejs folder

```
npm init
```

then I was going to create a local directory (say c:\develop\nodejs\ **upload2s3**), and create a nodejs package to use as AWS lambda. For this, i went into the local directory (upload2s3), and tried

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

though the command behaved like it installed things, this did not do anything in my **upload2s3** folder as it was empty.
then i just tried this in my local folder.

```
npm init
```

this created some **package.json**, and may be few other files
then i tried

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

then it created a **node-modules** folders inside my local folder (upload2s3) and installed the **aws-sdk** package.
It also updated the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "uploadtos32",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.448.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
pack=$(npm pack <package>) ; tar xzvf ${pack} --strip-components=1 ; rm ${pack} ; npm i
```

Comment: While your code may well solve the problem, please try and provide an explanation as to how/why the code in your answer will help the OP. Code-only answers do not always do a great job of explaining how to solve a problem, and certainly don't pass on knowledge to others very well.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not find any appropriate solution to simply install a standalone app from an npm registry.

You can download a tarball of the package by running `npm pack <package>`, extract the tarball by running `tar xvf <tarball_name>.tgz` and then install the dependencies by running `npm install --production` inside the extracted directory.

To streamline the whole process I created a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/mmende/2c10dd6161bc75120dbf153098caa48d) which could be executed directly from gist by running:

```sh
bash <(curl -sL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mmende/2c10dd6161bc75120dbf153098caa48d/raw/installNodeApp.sh) some-package ./package-installation
```