# Install Node Packages To Current Directory

Tags: node.js, npm

How do I get it so that node modules install into the current directory?

I have tried to google it and it says that simply running:

npm install

Should work. But this seems to always install to the user's home directory. How do I change this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have package.json? What is the content?

Comment: if you enter `pwd` in the terminal ? You are in the project folder or home folder ?

Comment: I am in the correct directory when I run pwd. I don't have a package.json that was the problem. I didn't realise if package.json is missing, it stores in the default directory. I assumed if it was missing it would create it (if you don't use the -g flag)

Comment: possible duplicate of [npm install module in current directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032160/npm-install-module-in-current-directory)

Comment: @Mohit I disagree. That other needs to be updated to show that npm can install to 1 of 3 directories. 1. Using -g flag put it in a system folder available to all users on the system 2. Missing package.json installs to users home folder. 3. If package.json exists, it install to the working directory.

Comment: `npm init` will help you create the package.json interactively :)

Answer (score 0):

Needed package.json file. Otherwise it will use the default node_modules folder... On my system it was set to user home folder.